# How to Recognize a Pattern in a Stream of Numbers

Tags: signal-processing

I have a stream of numbers (integers for the sake of discussion) being sampled off an analog input (a a/d converter attached to a potentiomeger). I am curious how I would recognize a pattern in the numbers in realtime.

That is to say, if someone quickly twiddles the pot all the way up and back down, how do I recognize that, vs if turn it only half way. Or what if they turn it up and down three times in a row. How can I convert these actions into distinct "events"? This seems especially tricky to me since the time window over which each of these events will occur will be modestly variable.

I can think of a few quick, hacky ways to do this, but nothing that I am confident in. I am also curious how one would expand this out to multiple different inputs (i.e. input off a spectrograph). Does that change things dramatically? I am not even sure what topic area I should be googling.

Comment: It's hard to know what you are asking. If the pot is encoded from 0-255 (say), then you can obviously distinguish turning all the way up from halfway by looking at the max from the stream: either it's 127 (half-way) or 255 (all the way). I think you need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: I mean all the way up as a loosely - they turn it up (maybe 100%, maybe 95%) and back down (maybe 0% , maybe 2%). My question is more like "How do I detect a hump in the signal? how do I distinguish variously shaped humps? What if the signal was more complex, like an audio input?"

Comment: Rather than saying what the question is "more like", you should say what the question actually is. What features of the "hump" are you actually interested in? Do you have sample data of a specific problem you are trying to solve? There are a myriad of solutions to solving different kinds of signal processing problems that are vaguely like the one you are describing.

Comment: I think its still a great question. Per the objective of the site, perhaps it could be more specific or have an example, but its still a great question. As the OP says, he doesn't even know what to google to learn about this. @BjornRoche, if you could post links to things SIMILAR that you mentioned, then perhaps the OP can refine his question. I know what he is looking for but, being in the same position as he is, find it difficult to verbalize it. He doesnt even know what features he CAN look for, for example. All he knows is that he wants to detect 'humps' in a datastream.

Comment: I think this will be a great question if we can get some more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you are looking for, correlate the input signal against a replica of what you expect. Basically, implement a matched filter. If you want to see when the input stream is -127, -63, 0, 63, 127, implement a direct form fir filter with these values as the coefficients. Then look for a maximum on the output. The maximum output of a filter with those coefficients occurs when the data in the filter is -127, -63, 0, 63, 127.

Google "Matched Filter Detection" or  or "detection theory" maybe even "Feature detection"

If you don't know exactly what you are looking for, or what you are looking for is variable, it gets more complicated. You would then try to implement a filter that's output would give you information about what is going on. The example that I gave above would show the output spike up when that input sequence occurred. If you then saw that spike occurring with regular frequency, you would guess that the input event was occurring with regular frequency.

if you made your filter 0, 63, 127 63 0, which correlates to turning the knob all the way up, and then back down again, and on your output saw the aforementioned spike occur, but having a lower maximum amplitude and wider time over which the correlation occurs, that might tell you that the know was turned all the way up and then back down, but either slower or faster than the speed for which the filter is design to get a maximum response.

To combat this you might implement 3 of these filters in parallel, one designed for a slow knob turn, one for a medium speed knob turn, and one for a fast knob turn. Then looking at the 3 outputs you get 3 different correlations which better help you understand what is occurring

Comment: I was thinking about this, and it occurred to me that I only talked about this in the time domain. There is also the whole frequency domain approach. For example, if you twiddle the knob very quickly, then the frequency content of our signal will contain high frequencies. If you twiddle the knob slow, your signal will contain low frequencies. If you wanted only to know when someone twiddled the knob fast, you would put your signal through a high-pass filter and measure the energy in the output. If there is no energy in the output, then the knob isn't being twiddled fast.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider taking the running difference of the signal (its differentiation)?